# How to attach custom data to elements?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

Is there any way to attach custom data to elements? Kind of like the $.data() function in jQuery?
I know you can subclass and element and add custom parameters, but it would be an overkill to create custom class just to add a single custom parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question....

You can create new properties on any given object at runtime using syntax like this:

```
myObject['newProperty'] = 'somevalue';
```

I'm not sure I'd recommend it in most situations.

Comment: thanks, this is what i'm looking for. Why don't you recommend it though?

Comment: it's not recommended because 1) dynamic classes have slower getter access times for performance 2) You're using magic strings that are prone to mistyping error when a constant could be used 3) You're screwing over the next guy who has to maintain your code because you didn't go strongly typed. If they have an instance of myObject, the IDE won't be able to autocomplete what it cannot see.

Comment: @John Because it defeats the purpose of using strong types, and goes around the various compiler checks against strong types leading to greater potential for runtime errors. If you need an "Associative Array/Dictionary" that is one thing.  But; I wouldn't go adding extra properties to any given object for the sole reason of avoiding creating your custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but would making your element a [dynamic class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html) satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I have to +1 this.  I also have no idea what the original poster is after; but this certainly sounds like it could be it.

Answer (score 1):

In Flex the `ItemRenderer` class (or [DataRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataRenderer.html#propertySummary)) has a `data` property filled when it's instanciated by a Flex control with a `dataProvider` (such as `List` or `DataGrid`).

Answer (score 1):

If your elements aren't dynamic, you can create Dictionary and use elements as a key to put any object with properties there:

```
var extraInfo:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
extraInfo[element1] = { tag : "Quick & dirty" };
// or
extraInfo[element2] = new ElementProperties("More solid approach");
```

Comment: Yes this is also a nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: For completeness; you can use that approach w/ any Object; you don't need to use a Dictionary.